# Comparing value from DateDiff function to other value in seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have defined in table columns that contains event start date, event stop date and TimePeriod in seconds.

When I try to run a query which will recognize where TimePeriod based on start and stop date was calculated wrongly:

```
WHERE
DATEDIFF(SECOND,a.EventStart,a.EventStop) <> a.TimePeriod
```

The output gives me values that actually match each other.

For example

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND,'2023-09-01 10:00:46.3530000','2023-09-01 10:51:44.2950000')
```

Returns 3058 what is equal to value in TimePeriod.

Is is something wrong with millisecond? How should I handle this?

Comment: `datediff()` only counts crossed boundaries: The distance from 11:59:59.999999am to noon is still counted as 1 even through they're only a fraction of a second apart. What is the resolution of `TimePeriod` and how was it calculated?

Comment: Are your Start and Stop dates always the same day? If so, then casting your dates to TIME in your query would likely work.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? datediff is a non-standard function.

Comment: @shawnt00 TimePeriod is in second resolution

Comment: @Isolated not always in the same day

Comment: @jarlh SQLServer

Comment: Was it calculated by truncating an accurate measurement of seconds, rounding, or by something like `datediff()`?

Comment: Perhaps you want something like `where datediff(second, EventStart, EventStop) > datediff(millisecond, EventStart, EventStop) / 1000`?

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle**
The date calculations depend, among other things, on datatypes involved in calculations. Maybe the example below, dates vs timestamps subtractions, could help you analize your data and code...

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e   D a t a :
    tbl (ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, START_TIMESTAMP, END_TIMESTAMP) AS
        ( Select 1, To_Date('2023-09-01 10:00:46', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), To_Date('2023-09-01 10:51:44', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),
                    To_TimeStamp('2023-09-01 10:00:46.3530000', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff'), To_TimeStamp('2023-09-01 10:51:44.2950000', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff')
          From   Dual 
         Union All
          Select 2, To_Date('2023-09-01 10:00:46', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), To_Date('2023-09-01 23:59:59', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),
                    To_TimeStamp('2023-09-01 10:00:46.3530000', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff'), To_TimeStamp('2023-09-01 23:59:59.9950000', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff')
          From   Dual 
        )
```

```sql
--    M a i n    S Q L :
Select  ID, 
        (END_DATE - START_DATE) * 24 * 60  * 60 "DATE_DIFF",
        (END_TIMESTAMP - START_TIMESTAMP) * 24 * 60  * 60 "TIMESTAMP_DIFF"
From    tbl
```

```sql
/*      R e s u l t (in seconds) :
ID DATE_DIFF                                    TIMESTAMP_DIFF
-- ------------------------------------------   -----------------------
1   3057,999999999999999999999999999999999998   +3057 22:36:28.800000
2   50353                                       +50353 15:24:28.800000  /*
```

Depending on how your TimePeriod column was generated you could use one of the functions (below) to get your result in seconds the same way as your TimePeriod column.

```sql
--    M a i n    S Q L :
Select  ID, 
        (END_DATE - START_DATE) * 24 * 60  * 60 "DATE_DIFF",
        ROUND((END_DATE - START_DATE) * 24 * 60  * 60, 0) "DATE_DIFF_ROUNDED_ZERO",
        CEIL((END_DATE - START_DATE) * 24 * 60  * 60) "DATE_DIFF_CEILED",
        FLOOR((END_DATE - START_DATE) * 24 * 60  * 60) "DATE_DIFF_FLOORED",
        (END_TIMESTAMP - START_TIMESTAMP) * 24 * 60  * 60 "TIMESTAMP_DIFF"
From    tbl
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
ID DATE_DIFF                                    DATE_DIFF_ROUNDED_ZERO  DATE_DIFF_CEILED DATE_DIFF_FLOORED TIMESTAMP_DIFF
-- -------------------------------------------- ----------------------- ---------------- ----------------- ------------------------
1   3057,999999999999999999999999999999999998                      3058            3058             3057   +3057 22:36:28.800000
2   50353                                                         50353        50353                50353  +50353 15:24:28.800000  */
```